# Amadeus PNR Retrieve

Tags: amadeus

I am implementing `Amadeus PNR Retrieve` using c# .net.

When processing the PNR reply, trying to map passenger data to our internal system. I was using `travellerInfo.elementManagementPassenger.reference.number` as the link between Amadeus passenger and internal system passenger record.

Below the case where it contains an infant along with two adult. Here infant record comes along with one of the adult and doesn't contain separate reference for the infant. Is anyone have idea about identifying all passengers uniquely?

```
<travellerInfo>
 <elementManagementPassenger>
      <reference>
        <qualifier>PT</qualifier>
        <number>2</number>
      </reference>
      <segmentName>NM</segmentName>
      <lineNumber>1</lineNumber>
 </elementManagementPassenger>
 <enhancedPassengerData>
      <enhancedTravellerInformation>
        <travellerNameInfo>
          <quantity>1</quantity>
          <infantIndicator>1</infantIndicator>
        </travellerNameInfo>
        <otherPaxNamesDetails>
          <nameType>UN</nameType>
          <referenceName>Y</referenceName>
          <displayedName>Y</displayedName>
          <surname>TESTER</surname>
          <givenName>TEST MR</givenName>
        </otherPaxNamesDetails>
      </enhancedTravellerInformation>
  </enhancedPassengerData>
  <enhancedPassengerData>
      <enhancedTravellerInformation>
        <travellerNameInfo>
          <quantity>1</quantity>
          <type>INF</type>
        </travellerNameInfo>
        <otherPaxNamesDetails>
          <nameType>UN</nameType>
          <referenceName>Y</referenceName>
          <displayedName>Y</displayedName>
          <surname>TESTER</surname>
          <givenName>TEST1 MSTR</givenName>
        </otherPaxNamesDetails>
      </enhancedTravellerInformation>
   </enhancedPassengerData>
</travellerInfo>
<travellerInfo>
   <elementManagementPassenger>
      <reference>
        <qualifier>PT</qualifier>
        <number>1</number>
      </reference>
      <segmentName>NM</segmentName>
      <lineNumber>2</lineNumber>
    </elementManagementPassenger>
   <enhancedPassengerData>
      <enhancedTravellerInformation>
        <travellerNameInfo>
          <quantity>1</quantity>
        </travellerNameInfo>
        <otherPaxNamesDetails>
          <nameType>UN</nameType>
          <referenceName>Y</referenceName>
          <displayedName>Y</displayedName>
          <surname>TESTER</surname>
          <givenName>TEST3 MRS</givenName>
        </otherPaxNamesDetails>
      </enhancedTravellerInformation>
   </enhancedPassengerData>
</travellerInfo>
```

Cost Information

```
<referenceForTstData>
  <reference>
    <qualifier>PT</qualifier>
    <number>1</number>
  </reference>
  <reference>
    <qualifier>ST</qualifier>
    <number>1</number>
  </reference>
  <reference>
    <qualifier>ST</qualifier>
    <number>2</number>
  </reference>
</referenceForTstData>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have contacted the Amadeus tech support and below is solution

In addition to checking the `referenceForTstData`, needs to check the `fareBasisInfo` element under `tstData`. It contains `ticketDesignator` which will be CH for child and INF for infant

```
  <fareBasisInfo>
      <fareElement>
        <primaryCode>xxx</primaryCode>
        <notValidBefore>xxx</notValidBefore>
        <notValidAfter>xxx</notValidAfter>
        <baggageAllowance>1PC</baggageAllowance>
        <fareBasis>2KU</fareBasis>
        <ticketDesignator>CH</ticketDesignator>
      </fareElement>         
    </fareBasisInfo>
```

Answer (score 2):

Infants refer to children under the age of 2, and PNRs can have 2 types of infants: lap infants (with Passenger Type Code=INF) who sit on the lap of an adult passenger for the duration of the flight, and infants with their own seat (INS).

Here you're seeing an INF type infant who shares the seat of their parent. Because they don't have their own seat, they are not a true passenger in the record, they are simply an extension of the adult passenger. They also don't have their own traveler ID. Any services you need for the infant will need to be associated to the parent's traveler ID instead.

You can see this much more clearly if you retrieve the record using the [Sandbox Travel Record API](https://sandbox.amadeus.com/travel-innovation-sandbox/apis/get/travel-record/%7Brecord_locator%7D).

Comment: Great! Other issue is when trying to link up the cost. I have the case where infant have some cost (Updated the question with sample) and the `referenceForTstData` contains reference number of the original adult so not sure how to differentiate the fareData is associated to adult or infant. Thanks

Comment: Each fare contains the Passenger Type Code (PTC) of the traveler. The fare with PTC=ADT is the fare for the adult, the fare with PTC=INF is the fare for the infant.

Comment: Thanks, do you know where this information can be found in xml with regards to `tstData` section. Couldn't recognised similar filed?

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure what message you're using, any version of PNR Reply I've used doesn't return much TST data. 

In the DisplayTSTReply v5.1, you can find the PTC at `/Ticket_DisplayTSTReply/fareList/statusInformation/firstStatusDetails/tstFlag`

Comment: I am using the web service PNR_Retrieve 14.1

Comment: Looking at a couple of examples, I don't see the PTC information returned anywhere in that reply message. You can try to use PNR_RetrieveAndDisplay, or display the TST to get this information

Comment: I have contacted Amadeus  regarding this and came to solution. I have posted as answer